# Collatz function path pattern?

Tags: pattern-recognition, collatz-conjecture

> **Definitions**
>
> $$C(n) =  \begin{cases} n/2 & n\equiv 0\pmod2 \\ 3n+1 & n\equiv 1\pmod2 \end{cases}$$
>
> Look at $C(n)$ for some $n$ and count how many times you multiply by
>   $3$ before reaching $1$, and add $1$ to that count. Call this the
>   *second path length* $L_2$ of that $n$ . Counting how many times we divide by two is the *first path length* $L_1$ of that $n$.

The *path length* of some $n$ is then just how many numbers $n$ jumps over before reaching $1$ *(including $1$, since $1$ was added to the count of $L_2$)* and is then $L_1+L_2$.

Trivial lengths can be directly seen in numbers of form $2^k$, which have $L_1=k$ and $L_2=1$ .

---

See the images if we take $L_1(n)\bmod9, L_2(n)\bmod6$,  and $(L_1(n)+L_2(n))\bmod15$, for $n=1\dots10^6$ and color pixels in shades of white (black) depending on the value of these three sequences (*such that consecutive remainders are close in shades of the color*), we get the following patterns:

- [$a_n= L_1(n)\bmod9$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ApBo.png)
- [$a_n= L_2(n)\bmod6$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R86Kq.png)
- [$a_n= (L_1(n)+L_2(n))\bmod15$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLQhT.png)

These particular $9,6,15$ mod values are the best for the smoothest transition of color shades.

Each pixel represents a single value of $a_n$, which were placed and colored on the images from left to right, from up to down. We can draw the graph from the center to the edges, in a spiral manner on a square lattice, and get the same patterns but *spiralized*:

- [$a_n= L_1(n)\bmod9$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKaxy.png)
- [$a_n= L_2(n)\bmod6$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0r5S.png)
- [$a_n= (L_1(n)+L_2(n))\bmod15$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61izR.png)

The $L$ patterns form simple periodic regions which are increasing in size as $n$ grows.

> Why do patterns look like that? What does that tells us?

Also; For comparison, you can see sequences $n\bmod k$ for same $k=6,9,15$ normal and spiral, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/His49.png), for $n=1\dots4096$ *(smaller images as their patterns are tiny and repeat exactly)*.

---

We can look at $L_2$ for example, and:

We can go ahead and use $6$ colors *(red,yellow,green,cyan,blue,purple)* for the $L_2$ pattern.

Plot $a_n=L_2(n)$ sequence such that we color lengths of form $(6k-5,6k-4,6k-3,6k-2,6k-1,6k)$ with the corresponding colors.

The shades of each of $6$ colors depend on $k$. We get the following image:

[image]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS0ow.jpg) is the spiral version.

What does this show? For example, numbers $900,000$ to $945,000$ are the numbers in the most bottom blue region, which means that if those numbers are plugged in the $C(n)$ function, we know that most $L_2$ paths of those $n$ will be of form $6k-1$.

Or for example, when picking a random number from the red interval (region), and plugging it into the collatz function, we are expecting to most likely perform $6k-5$ multiplications *(actually $6k-6$ since $1$ was added in definition of $L_2$ at the beginning of the post)* by $3$ before reaching $1$, where average $k$ depends on the size of $n$.

> Was this observed before? Can one estimate the sizes of these periodic
>   regions? 
> For $L_1,L_2$ and $L_1+L_2$?
>
> Can this tell us anything about the collatz function or is it just a neat observation?
>
> Why are $L_2\bmod6$ and $L_1\bmod9$ least messy patterns?

For example, using $L_2\bmod 5$  instead of $L_2\bmod6$ *(and coloring)*, we get [this mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6zBE.png).

Using $2,3,4$ are still almost as nice as $6$, but after that its similar to $5$.

Comment: These graphs reminded me of Kirby Banman's visualization he called, "Eye of Collatz". http://kdbanman.com/2016/09/23/eye-of-collatz/ Banman used a different method involving a spiral grid, but Banman's visualizations also had a "stripe" effect.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer but some things i noticed that might be linked to what you saw.

The more $n$ is big, the more you have successive numbers having the same $L_x$ values (...and modulo). I didn't explore this yet.

$
\small n\quad\quad\quad \scriptsize L_2(n)\> L_1(n) \quad  \text{number of division by two (comma $\to$ 3n+1) to reach 1:}\\
...\\
900310\quad26\quad61\quad(1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,8,2,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
900311\quad26\quad61\quad(0,1,1,4,1,2,2,2,1,8,2,2,2,1,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
900312\quad26\quad61\quad(3,1,2,1,1,1,4,1,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
900313\quad26\quad61\quad(0,2,1,5,1,2,2,1,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
900314\quad26\quad61\quad(1,3,2,1,1,1,4,1,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
900315\quad26\quad61\quad(0,1,2,1,1,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
900316\quad26\quad61\quad(2,1,1,3,1,1,4,1,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
900317\quad26\quad61\quad(0,3,1,3,1,1,4,1,1,3,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,4,1,1,10)\\
...\\
901474\quad17\quad47...\\
901475\quad17\quad47...\\
901476\quad17\quad47...\\
901477\quad17\quad47...\\
901478\quad17\quad47...\\
...\\
902209\quad53\quad104...\\
902210\quad53\quad104...\\
902211\quad53\quad104...\\
902212\quad53\quad104...\\
902213\quad53\quad104...\\
902214\quad53\quad104...\\
...$

The ratio $\frac{L_1(n)}{L_2(n)}$ is also discussed here: ([What causes this apparent pattern in hailstone sequences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2412846/what-causes-this-apparent-pattern-in-hailstone-sequences/2413040#2413040))