# Collatz sequence lengths for Primorials

Tags: collatz-conjecture, primorial

The primorial $(\#)$ function is defined as the product of first $n$ prime numbers. Is there a simple explanation for the observation that the [length of the Collatz sequence for successive primorials](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/abbott/Published/PrimorialCollatz.nb) increases linearly with $\log{\# (n)}$?

Comment: Didn't check yet, but I suspect a behaviour like here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2412846/what-causes-this-apparent-pattern-in-hailstone-sequences/2413040